# Volume of Oxygen Produced By Electrolysis of Water

Tags: physical-chemistry, water, electrolysis

I am trying to estimate the volume of oxygen that will be produced by electrolysis of water at normal temperature and pressure with a current of $\pu{50 A}$. The following is my calculation:

The reaction is
$$\ce{2H2O -> O2 + 4H+ + 4e-}$$

Therefore, to produce $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{O2}$ ($\pu{24 L}$), we need to move $\pu{4 mol}$ of electrons through the circuit and this is $4F = 4 \times 9.65 \times 10^4 = \pu{3.86 \times 10^5 C}$ of charge. With a current of $\pu{50 A}$, we move $50 \times 60 = \pu{3000 C}$ of charge per minute. Therefore, we produce $\frac{24}{3.86 \times 10^5} \times 3000 = \pu{0.186 L}$ of $\ce{O2}$ per minute.

Is this calculation correct? If it is, is there any way to improve the yield of oxygen?

**Disclaimer**: I am not a chemist and it has been years since I studied physical chemistry. The reason for this computation is to decide if electrolysis is a quick and feasible method to produce oxygen to help mild COVID patients at home (since there is a severe shortage of oxygen and concentrators where I live).

Comment: Your calculation is correct : $0.186 $L per minute. The electrolysis is not a quick method for producing large amounts of oxygen gas. On the other hand, the electrolysis of water would produce Hydrogen at the other electrode. How to separate these two gases ?  Furthermore, it is extremely difficult to conduct any electrolytic operation with such a high currant ($50 A$). You would need huge electrodes, because whatever the nature  of the electrode used, the current is highly dependent on the surface of the electrode. The upper limit is of the order of $\pu{0.1 - 1 A/dm^2}$.

Comment: Thanks for checking my calculation @Maurice. The plan was to use large quantities of wrapped up stainless steel mesh to make the electrodes and have tubes enclosing the electrodes to separate the gases at the source. And since a large amount of heat would be generated, we were planning to setup a cooling system enclosing the electrolysis chamber. But considering the small amount of oxygen produced, we will switch to using a zeolite based method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your idea and help.
I think that your calculations are correct.

But I think you'd better to try other simpler choices to make oxygen.

One way is air separation. If you separate nitrogen from air, you gain oxygen.
This can be done by "Zeolite oxygen generators". You can read these site about them.
1- https://www.zeochem.com/our-applications/medical-oxygen-generation
2- https://www.jalonzeolite.com/product-item/molecular-sieve-jlox-500/

There are many important factors that you have to consider about electrolysis of water that I know some of them:

```
First water has low conductivity. So, you have to add a strong inert electrolyte to make charge transfer between electrodes. This electrolyte could be any soluble salt, an acid or any substance that solves in water and then dissociates to ions. But, the electrolyte must not interacts to the main reaction and should be inert and surely it should be absolutely safe and not harmful for patient. Sodium or potassium sulfate or nitrate can be used.
```

Next, you have to choose an inert electrode to conduct electricity to the solution and then the gas be produced on it. Platin and gold can be use. But, they are expensive. Another choice can be carbon electrode.
And also take care about Hydrogen that produced on the negative electrode (cathode), that is flammable and can be exploded by spark.
And, so many other considerations to make oxygen efficiently and, next purify it to be suitable for hospital usage.

I wish you health.